# How to rename a column and add an unspecified column in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my db:

```
class Agent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'agent'
    ip_address = Column(IPAddressType, nullable=True)    
    target_type = 1
```

DB doesn't store *target_type*, so I specified it without Column().

I want to rename *ip_address* into *address*.

Approach 1:

```
agents = db.session.query(Agent, Agent.target_type, Agent.ip_address.label("address")).all()
```

This approach can rename *ip_address*, but it's *target_type* is **0**

Approach 2:

```
agents = Agent.query.all()
```

This approach cannot rename *ip_address*, but it's *target_type* is **1**

I understand *db.session* is the right way to rename a column, but I don't understand why it cannot get the right *target_type*.

Comment: I get 1 as the value of target type for both approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add following code in db design

```
class Agent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'agent'
    ip_address = Column(IPAddressType, nullable=True)    
    target_type = 1
    address = ip_address
```

In this way, using approach 2 can make it.